# Событие ondragleave отслеживаемое на document срабатывает на всех элементах

Tags: drag-n-drop, javascript

Привет, столкнулся с проблемой при отслеживании "ondragleave".

Идея в том, чтобы при попытке перетянуть файл в браузер, показывались поля, куда можно его "скинуть" (как в ВК на своей странице).
Я повесил обработчик события "ondragenter" на "document", чтобы когда пользователь начинал, на странице происходили действия (добавление класса к объекту в который нужно сбрасывать файл, не важно).
Дальше я повесил обработчик события "ondragleave" на тот же "document", чтобы вернуть страницу к исходному виду если вдруг пользователь внезапно передумал.

Так вот, если курсором с файлом крутить по всей странице поля то и дело, что появляются и пропадают.
Почему так происходит? Почему событие срабатывает на всех элементах страницы, а не только при входе/выходе с браузера?

(пробовал вешать и на html и на body и на "window" результат тот же)

Answer (score 1):

Потому что так [спроектировано](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/dragleave).

Comment: Как быть ?

Comment: Я делаю [так][1].

[1]: https://github.com/mailru/FileAPI/blob/dev/lib/FileAPI.core.js#L1457

Comment: Спасибо, твой пример натолкнул меня на идею, которая вроде как работает.
Заключается в сохранении объекта на котором сработало событие "ondragenter", обрабатывать "ondragleave" только в случае выхода из того же объекта.
Проблему решило..

Comment: Правильно реагировать на событие `dragleave`, через `setTimeout`, который сбрасывать на dragenter.

Comment: какой в этом смысл?

Comment: @RubaXa действительно какой ? кроме как в случае `setTimeout(action,0)` я смысла не вижу.

Comment: @eicto, @nd-dd, чтобы получить "нормальные" события dragenter/dragleave. Сейчас же они обладают теми же проблемам, что и mouseover/mouseout, т.е. бросаются при перемещении между DOM-элементами.

Comment: так есть же target у события.